# Structured data, dictionaries inside lists

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, pandas, dictionary

I am trying to have my data (lists with dictionaries) structured, to do that I used pandas df.

I was trying to replicate without using pandas, I tried with zip and pop, but I couldn't reach anything similar to what I get using pandas df.

Even with pandas df pivot, the output is what I want but I am loosing the 'name', and I would like to have the data structured for all names.

My question is can I get a similar output without using pandas, and why it is not printing a table for all names?

```
rec =[{'date': u'2018-01-21', 'name' : u'John', 'fieldname': u'lunch', 'fieldvalue': u'10'},
 {'date': u'2018-01-21', 'name' : u'John', 'fieldname': u'dinner', 'fieldvalue': u'9'},
 {'date': u'2018-01-22', 'name' : u'John', 'fieldname': u'lunch', 'fieldvalue': u'11'},
 {'date': u'2018-01-22', 'name' : u'John', 'fieldname': u'dinner', 'fieldvalue': u'8'},
 {'date': u'2018-01-23', 'name' : u'John', 'fieldname': u'lunch', 'fieldvalue': u'12'},
 {'date': u'2018-01-23', 'name' : u'John', 'fieldname': u'dinner', 'fieldvalue': u'5'}]
[{'date': u'2018-01-21', 'name' : u'Anna', 'fieldname': u'lunch', 'fieldvalue': u'11'},
 {'date': u'2018-01-21', 'name' : u'Anna', 'fieldname': u'dinner', 'fieldvalue': u'8'},
 {'date': u'2018-01-22', 'name' : u'Anna', 'fieldname': u'lunch', 'fieldvalue': u'13'},
 {'date': u'2018-01-22', 'name' : u'Anna', 'fieldname': u'dinner', 'fieldvalue': u'9'},
 {'date': u'2018-01-23', 'name' : u'Anna', 'fieldname': u'lunch', 'fieldvalue': u'11'},
 {'date': u'2018-01-23', 'name' : u'Anna', 'fieldname': u'dinner', 'fieldvalue': u'15'}]
[{'date': u'2018-01-21', 'name' : u'John', 'fieldname': u'lunch', 'fieldvalue': u'14'},
 {'date': u'2018-01-21', 'name' : u'John', 'fieldname': u'dinner', 'fieldvalue': u'3'},
 {'date': u'2018-01-22', 'name' : u'John', 'fieldname': u'lunch', 'fieldvalue': u'16'},
 {'date': u'2018-01-22', 'name' : u'John', 'fieldname': u'dinner', 'fieldvalue': u'9'},
 {'date': u'2018-01-23', 'name' : u'John', 'fieldname': u'lunch', 'fieldvalue': u'12'},
 {'date': u'2018-01-23', 'name' : u'John', 'fieldname': u'dinner', 'fieldvalue': u'9'}]
[{'date': u'2018-01-21', 'name' : u'Brian', 'fieldname': u'lunch', 'fieldvalue': u'11'},
 {'date': u'2018-01-21', 'name' : u'Brian', 'fieldname': u'dinner', 'fieldvalue': u'13'},
 {'date': u'2018-01-22', 'name' : u'Brian', 'fieldname': u'lunch', 'fieldvalue': u'12'},
 {'date': u'2018-01-22', 'name' : u'Brian', 'fieldname': u'dinner', 'fieldvalue': u'8'},
 {'date': u'2018-01-23', 'name' : u'Brian', 'fieldname': u'lunch', 'fieldvalue': u'11'},
 {'date': u'2018-01-23', 'name' : u'Brian', 'fieldname': u'dinner', 'fieldvalue': u'15'}]

df(rec)

         date fieldname fieldvalue  name
0  2018-01-21     lunch         10  John
1  2018-01-21    dinner          9  John
2  2018-01-22     lunch         11  John
3  2018-01-22    dinner          8  John
4  2018-01-23     lunch         12  John
5  2018-01-23    dinner          5  John

df(rec).pivot(index='date', columns='fieldname', values='fieldvalue')

fieldname  dinner lunch
date                   
2018-01-21      9    10
2018-01-22      8    11
2018-01-23      5    12
```

Output desired:

```
Anna
fieldname  dinner lunch
date                   
2018-01-21      9    10
2018-01-22      8    11
2018-01-23      5    12

John
fieldname  dinner lunch
date                   
2018-01-21      9    10
2018-01-22      8    11
2018-01-23      5    12

Brian
fieldname  dinner lunch
date                     
2018-01-21      9    10
2018-01-22      8    11
2018-01-23      5    12
```

Comment: How do you want lines in the the table sorted, and what should its heading be?

Comment: One thing I see: with the data structured as it is in `rec` the dataframe will have only the data for John.

Comment: @Bill Bell, edit my question with the pretended output. the header should be the date, dinner, and lunch. and the name of the table should be the name(i.e John).

Comment: What are you trying to do with the four lists of dictionaries? Should they be in a list of their own? Or okay to append them into a single list?

Comment: My goal it is to reproduce without pandas in a simple way the table that I am getting using pandas dataframe. @ Kirk Broadhurst.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works under 3 conditions:

1. Turn your input into a list of dictionaries.
2. Drop duplicates or specify a suitable aggregation function.
3. Convert string `fieldvalue` column to numeric.

**Solution**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(rec).drop_duplicates(['date', 'name', 'fieldname'])
df['fieldvalue'] = pd.to_numeric(df['fieldvalue'], downcast='integer')

dfs = {k: pd.pivot_table(df[df['name'] == k], index=['date'],
          columns=['fieldname'], values=['fieldvalue']) \
          for k in set(df['name'])}
```

**Result**

Since I have used the `drop_duplicates` option above, you may see different results to your desired output.

```
{'Brian':            fieldvalue      
fieldname      dinner lunch
date                       
2018-01-21         13    11
2018-01-22          8    12
2018-01-23         15    11,

 'Anna':            fieldvalue      
fieldname      dinner lunch
date                       
2018-01-21          8    11
2018-01-22          9    13
2018-01-23         15    11,

 'John':            fieldvalue      
fieldname      dinner lunch
date                       
2018-01-21          9    10
2018-01-22          8    11
2018-01-23          5    12}
```

Comment: Using pandas your answer is working, but there is any other option of having a similar output but not as a dict. I am trying to use sqlite3 to do that, but my goal is to do it as simple as possible. I tried to use DictWriter to output the data in a tabular way, but give the values to the fieldName is becoming a hard task.

Comment: The way I would do this is, if viable, output each dataframe from the dictionary to a separate excel worksheet. This is very easy to do via `pandas`. Otherwise, why not just add the name in a column rather than as a heading and forget about splitting into separate dataframes?